# app.delete not deleting the document from collection

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to use app.delete to remove the document from my database collection.Initially, it worked fine, but then mongodb showed a warning that .remove is deprecated and use .deleteOne. So, when i used .deleteOne , it did not delete the document, and i get back to .remove. But now, it is also not working.I am using POSTMAN to check.

```
const Hospital = require('./model/hospital-model')
app.delete('/hospitals/placeid=:id',async (req,res) => {
    const placeid= req.params.id
    console.log(placeid)
    await Hospital.remove({placeid:placeid},(err,Hospitals)=>{
        if(err){
            res.send('error')
            next();
        }
        console.log('The hospital has been deleted from database')
        res.send('The hospital has been deleted from database')
    })
})
```

Comment: Could you share the hospital-model code?

Comment: Try using that same criteria in a 'find' to make sure it actually matches.

Comment: It has started working again. I do not know what the problem was.